SQLAlchemy Event Listeners - Best Way to get update values while using do_orm_execute
When using sqlalchemy event listeners, I'm wondering the recommended/best way to get the actual updated values while using the do_orm_execute session event.
For example, when detecting ORM events using something like before_flush I can do something like:
def _before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    for entry in session.dirty:
        # below would print the class instance of my updated table row
        print(entry)
event.listen(session, "before_flush", _before_flush)

I'm hoping to find a (at least nearly) analogous way of detecting updates that were made through execute() statements using do_orm_execute.
def _receive_orm_execute(orm_execute_state: ORMExecuteState):
    if orm_execute_state.is_update:
        # what is the best way to grab updates here?
        # the following seems to have tuples with updated field values, but should I be using this:
        # orm_execute_state.execution_options['_sa_orm_update_options']._resolved_keys_as_propnames

event.listen(session, "do_orm_execute", _receive_orm_execute)

Either of the above requires more setup than just dropping in these snippets.  But I am assuming anyone with an answer to this question will not need it.
This question really boils down to - what is the best/recommended way to do this?
FWIW:  using sqlalchemy v1.4.x (due to project constraints) but will take insights from any version.
Thanks in advance.

Asked and answered on GitHub here

yeah that was me lol.
